# How to map a number to range

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to map a given value to a range of values. Eg I am trying to do this for percentage obtained by students in a class. Rather than storing individual percentage I want to store the range of 5. Eg. for 72%, the range would be `70 to 75`. how can i do this.

I want to use dictionary for doing this, but not able to figure out how. Want  to do something like:

```
mydict = {range(0,5):"0 to 5", range(5,10):"5 to 10" ... }
```

Is there a way of doing this?

**EDIT:** I want to do this using dictionary

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make a dictionary.

```
>>> n = 72
>>> base = n // 5 * 5
>>> '{} to {}'.format(base, base+5)
'70 to 75'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want dictionary, you can do something like:

```
{k:"{} to {}".format(k - (k%5),5+k - (k%5)) for k in range(MAX_VAL)}
```

this way, every number will point to the desired string.

However, I believe that @falsetru's answer is better for your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of numbers (e.g. a list of scores for students), you can use numpy.digitize to map the values into the index of predefined bins of abitary size.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

For example:

```
>>>scores = [72, 45, 28, 10, 92]
>>>bins = [0, 40, 55, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
>>>numpy.digitize(scores, bins)
array([5, 2, 1, 1, 7])
```

If you want the bin index to be output to a range in terms of a string, you can make a simple function:

```
def range_str(index, bins):
    return '{} to {}'.format(bins[index-1], bins[index])
```

e.g.

```
>>>range_str(5, bins)
'70 to 80'
```